# Change all the string values in Excel column?

Tags: excel

I have a column. THe column is the number 2 all the way down.

What is the fastest way to make all the cells in this column a 3?

The values are of string datatype I believe.

Answer (score 31):

- Click the first "2" cell
- Press Control+Shift+DownArrow
- Press the 3 key
- Press Control+Enter
- See if it did what you thought you wanted

Comment: In case that you want to fill a column up to a specific row, you can use this solution, and then remove the extra rows using the same solution.